# traefik docker basic exemple return 404

Tags: docker, traefik

I'm starting to use treafix but I facing a wall. I'm trying to start with the basic docker example provided here : https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/user-guides/docker-compose/basic-example/

```
version: "3.8"

services:

  traefik:
    image: "traefik:v2.3"
    container_name: "traefik"
    command:
      - "--log.level=DEBUG"
      - "--accessLog"
      - "--api.insecure=true"
      - "--providers.docker=true"
      - "--providers.docker.exposedbydefault=false"
      - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro"

  whoami:
    image: "traefik/whoami"
    container_name: "simple-service"
    labels:
      - "traefik.enable=true"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.entrypoints=web"
      - "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host('server.local')"
```

As I'm local, I've set up "server.local" in my hostfile to point to 127.0.0.1

However, when I run it with compose and try to access my server.local I only got a 404, not the whoami expected response. I don't see anything that jump to me as wrong within the logs but again, I'm starting in, the traefik area.

I'm using docker desktop on windows wityh WSL2 and running the compose inside an ubuntu WSL2 vm

Answer (score 0):

I found my issue :

In the traefik rule, you should only use **backtick** (`) and **not** a single quote (') to define string litteral

so my :

```
- "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host('server.local')"
```

should be

```
- "traefik.http.routers.whoami.rule=Host(`server.local`)"
```

I wished the traefik documentation made this much more clear, especially in the default exemples ...